# Access Magento API Login method in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magento, cordova

Can some body explain how to call the login method from magento API in phonegap with username and apikey. I have tried few samples from stackoverflow and other sites but no results. Can some one please show any working javascript/jquery code to access the magento API.

Comment: What have you tried and what error messages did you get? Are you using the REST or SOAP Magento API ?

Comment: I am using SOAP V2 Magento API i tried using $.ajax({}) in javascript and inserted url, methodname, parameters in it, but is returning empty string always